# При нажатие копируем текст

Tags: jquery, html, php, css

Подскажите как более лучше сделать ?

При нажатие на текст/или ссылку текст копируется в опред. поле

http://hls.url.ph/new_message.php - вот тут форма сама, справа список друзей при нажатие на на одного из них текст на который нажали копируется в поле Имя получателя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Делаем все красиво и нацеливаемся на продолжительную разработку, смену стилей и прочего (даже если это тестовый проект). Поэтому элементы друзей, на которые можно нажимать, помечаем атрибутом `role="friend-selector"`. Этот атрибут никак не зависит от верстки и поэтому позволит менять содержимое страницы чуть ли не как угодно, не ломая при этом логику яваскрипта. В тот же элемент добавляем атрибут `data-friend-id="%id%"` или просто `data-id="%id%"` (%id% заменяется на реальный идентификатор пользователя) - так мы получаем реальный айдишник этого пользователя.
2. Точно так же делаем с формой - на инпуте, который соответствует имени друга, создаем атрибут `role="selected-friends-display"`, а самой форме - `role="message-form"`.
3. Теперь можно сделать непосредственно связку. При нажатии на "друга" его имя должно попасть в список, а также должен быть создан соответствующий инпут с айдишником, чтобы сообщить серверу о том, что друг выбран. Соответственно при клике на `role="friend-selector"` берется его текст и атрибут `data-friend-id`, после чего создается инпут внутри элемента `role="message-form"` и обновляется значение элемента `role="selected-friends-display"`

   ```
   var name = $(this).text(); // получаем то, что находится в элементе
   selectedFriends[id] = name; // добавляем друга к выбранным
   $('<input>', {
       'role': 'selected-friend-id-input',
       'data-friend-id': id,
       'type': 'hidden',
       'name': 'recipients[]',
   }).appendTo($messageForm); // создаем инпут, который сообщит серверу, какой именно это друг
   ```

[живой пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnygv/)

p.s. наименования ролей здесь довольно убогие, не стоит их брать за референс

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте ваш обработчик с

```
ico.on('click', function(){
    switch ($(this).data('type')){
        case 'b':
            ta.val( ta.val() + '<b></b>' );
            break;
    }
});
```

на

```
ico.on('click', function() {
    switch ($(this).data('type')){
        case 'b':
            ta.val($(this).text());
            break;
    }
});
```

должно сработать